# German translation of "case sensitive"

Tags: translation, english-to-german, compound

As a translation of **case sensitive** [dict.cc](https://www.dict.cc/?s=case%20sensitive) offered

- Groß- / Kleinschreibung-unterscheidend
- schreibungsabhängig, and
- Groß- / Kleinschreibung (beachten)!

None of these are as elegant as the English term. Any suggestions?

#### Example Context

An example would be the German [mozilla.org page "Mit Objekten arbeiten"](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Mit_Objekten_arbeiten) (translation of [Working with Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)). The question occurred at

> Like all JavaScript variables, both the object name (which could be a normal variable) and property name are **case sensitive**.

Comment: Im deutschen Wikipediaartikel heißt es "case-sensitiv" (https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Case_sensitivity). Das hatte ich nicht erwartet...

Comment: @Iris: Trotzdem gute Idee, Wikipedia zu fragen.

Comment: @user: Wikipedia zu fragen ist eine gute Idee, sich darauf zu verlassen ist es aber nicht.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since

> **(a)** case sensitive = case has a meaning
>
> **(b)** case insensitive = case has no meaning

one could translate it to

> **(a)** groß/klein-relevant
>
> **(b)** groß/klein-irrelevant

Example sentence:

> Zeichenketten werden grundsätzlich groß/klein-relevant verglichen.
>   *(Strings are generally compared case sensitive.)*

Answer (score 13):

Keep *case-sensitive* as a foreign word, or use a ‎supporting sentence instead of a participle construction ("wobei Groß- und Kleinschreibung unterschieden wird").

As usual, the best actual choice depends on the context. 
In general, you can find examples on [linguee.de](http://www.linguee.de/deutsch-englisch/search?source=auto&query=case+sensitive).
I've never seen a German term for this.

For your example I'd write:

> Wie bei allen JavaScript-Variablennamen sind sowohl beim Namen des Objekts (was eine normale Variable sein kann) als auch beim Namen der Eigenschaft Groß- und Kleinschreibung signfikant.

*Signifikant* is the technical term for lexical properties of variables of a programming language, if I remember correctly that goes back at least as far as [Wirth](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Niklaus_Wirth).

When introducing properties, I'd also add *property* in parenthesis (another technical term where the English name is widely used):

> ... Eigenschaft (auf Englisch *property*)

Comment: Wäre case-sensitiv besser als case-sensitive?

Comment: @gnasher: Nein, *case-sensitiv* ist eine extrem merkwürdige Mischform. Entweder Englisch oder Deutsch, aber bitte kein Denglisch.

Answer (score 13):

[I hope an answer in German is fine; in a nutshell: you can try a [neologism](/questions/tagged/neologism), but there is no intuitive good one.]

Es gibt m.W. tatsächlich keinen etablierten „deutscheren“ Begriff für *case-[in]sensitive*, also für die Unterscheidung von Groß- und Kleinbuchstaben. Man könnte allerdings einen Neologismus bilden:

Von bspw. *context-sensitive* wissen wir, dass der zweite Teil des Kompositums als *-abhängig, -sensibel, -sensitiv* oder *-spezifisch* ins Deutsche übertragen werden kann; in anderen Kontexten taucht außerdem *-empfindlich* auf. Sie alle können mit *un+* negiert werden. 
Wenn ich im folgenden *abhängig* schreibe, kann es meist auch durch die genannten Alternativen ersetzt werden.

Die *lower-case letters* heißen auf Deutsch *Gemeine, Minuskeln* oder *Kleinbuchstaben*, *upper-case / capital letters* sind *Versalien, Majuskeln* oder *Großbuchstaben*. Leider sind *klein* und *groß* keine besonders spezifischen Begriffe und das entsprechend gebildete ***größen[un]abhängig*** ist zwar an sich gebräuchlich, aber für den Zweck (ähnlich ***(groß-/klein)schreibungs[un]abhängig***) zu ungenau; gleichzeitig ist *Buchstabe* ein ziemlich langes und damit umständliches Wort ohne gutes Synonym, da *Zeichen* ist wieder ziemlich allgemein ist, weswegen ***buchstabengrößen[un]abhängig*** nicht besonders attraktiv erscheint – im richtigen Kontext wäre das gerade schon fast ausgeschlossene ***zeichengrößen[un]abhängig*** sogar womöglich besser.

[image: Setzkasten]

Das englische *case* kommt aus dem manuellen Bleisatz, wo Groß- und Kleinbuchstaben in unterschiedlichen Fächern des Setzkastens liegen, nämlich hinten/oben (*upper*) und vorne/unten (*lower*), da man die Gemeinen viel häufiger benötigt als die Versalien. Heute noch einen neuen Bezug auf die Schriftsetzerei prägen zu wollen, dürfte aussicht- und sinnlos sein.
Man kann *case* hier also nicht mit *Fall* und damit die Zusammensetzung nicht zu ***fall[un]abhängig*** übersetzen.
Im Englischen heißen Schriften mit zwei alternativen Gruppen von Buchstabenformen *bicameral* (wie Parlamente mit zwei Kammern) und fachsprachlich gibt es auch auf Deutsch *bikameral*, das sich besser ins Laut- und Schriftsystem einzufügen vermag als *case*. 
Daraus könnte man mit Adjektiv-zu-Adjektiv-Ableitung ein neues Wort bilden, dem die entsprechende Bedeutung aufgeprägt werden soll, bspw. ***(bi)kameralisch, (bi)kameralistisch*** oder ***(bi)kameralitär***. Das wäre allerdings sehr intransparent.

[image: typographisches Liniensystem]

Alle Großbuchstaben erstrecken sich vertikal über die beiden Hauptbänder, stehen dabei auf der [Grundlinie](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liniensystem_(Typografie)). Alle Kleinbuchstaben haben ihren Hauptteil im mittleren Band, können aber auch Teile (sog. Ober- bzw. Unterlänge) im Ober- oder Unterband, selten auch in allen drei haben. Leider gewinnt man auch mit ***längen[un]abhängig*** oder ***band[un]abhängig*** nichts überzeugendes dazu. 
Beide sind aber immerhin treffender als ***form(en)[un]abhängig***, da sie auf die vertikale Ausdehnung beschränkt sind. 
An der Einschätzung ändert sich auch wiederum nichts, wenn man noch *buchstaben-* oder *zeichen-* voranstellen würde.

Fazit: Auch nach einer Stunde puzzeln habe ich keinen signifikant besseren Vorschlag anzubieten als sich in ein paar Jahrhunderten deutscher Typographie- und Schriftsatztradition etabliert haben.

Comment: Auch ein Neologismus hätte den Nachteil, dass ihn kein Schwein versteht. Man will mit Sprache ja eigentlich vor allem kommunizieren.

Comment: @dirkt Darum hatte ich versucht, etwas einigermaßen transparentes neuzuschöpfen, aber das ist in diesem Fall offebar nicht so einfach. Prinzipiell spricht aber nichts gegen Neologismen – manche setzen sich durch, andere nicht.

Comment: Der Zug für einen Neologismus für diesen Begriff ist schon lange abgefahren; das Konzept *case-sensitive* usw. gibt es seit 30 Jahren im Deutschen. Neologismen funktioneren nur dann, wenn ein Begriff gerade neu eingeführt wird. Dann gibt es in der Tat oft verschiedene Ansätze, bis sich einer durchsetzt.

Comment: die aufgeführten Bilder finde ich übertrieben.

Comment: Wie wär’s mit __groß-klein-abhängig__ und __groß-klein-unabhängig__?

Comment: @dirkt: Gibt es dafür einen treffenden Beweis oder ist das einfach eine aus der Luft gegriffene Behauptung?

Comment: @userunknown: Gibt es wofür einen treffenden Beweis? Dass es case-sensitive schon seit 30 Jahren gibt? Dazu bin z.B. ich der Beweis, denn ich kenne den Begriff seit 30 Jahren, ich habe den bisher nur als Fremdwort gesehen und verwendet, und ich habe nie einen deutschen Begriff dafür gesehen. Wenn Du einen schriftlichen Beweis willst, könnte man auch Informatik-Lehrbücher aus der entsprechenden Zeit durchsuchen (ich hätte da ein paar); da es die aber idR.  nur in Papier- und nicht in elektronischer Form gibt, ist das etwas aufwendig.

Comment: @dirkt Ich glaube es ging eher um deine steile These: „Neologismen funktioneren nur dann, wenn ein Begriff gerade neu eingeführt wird.“ Dafür gibt es bspw. aus den Eindeutschungsbemühungen französischer Begriffe im 19. Jahrhundert zahlreiche Gegenbeispiele. Eine frühe Einführung ist sicher hilfreich, aber weder notwendig noch ausreichend für den Erfolg eines Neologismus.

Comment: @dirkt: Ja, wie Crissov schreibt.

Comment: @userunknown: Ich stimme dem zu, dass prinzipiell ein Neologismus auch funktionieren kann, wenn er spät eingeführt wird, nur halte ich es bei diesem Beispiel für *extrem* unwahrscheinlich. In der Informatik gibt es bereits sehr viele englische Begriffe, und der Trend geht eher dahin, auch eingedeutschte Begriffe wieder durch die englischen Begriffe zu ersetzen als umgekehrt. Ich sehe also hier keinerlei Erfolgschance für einen Neologismus. Das ist natürlich nur meine Meinung, und so etwas kann man prinzipiell nicht beweisen, aber ich schließe gerne eine Wette ab. :-)

Comment: +1 for the etymology of "case" and for demonstrating, that there is no german equivalent.

Comment: +1 für *bikameral*, welches offenbar als einzige hier genannte Lösung als Ansatz für ein Wort taugt, das auch passt, wenn es bei der case-sensitivity nicht um Groß-/Kleinschreibung geht, sondern um beliebige andere "cases" eines (exotischen, erfundenen, ...) Schriftsystems.

Answer (score 3):

Observation: All text processors at hand use one of these or close variants. If in search of a click box label within a search dialog I find

> a ≠ A

quite international and hard to beat.

There is of course no guarantee, to find a phrase with similar elegance for any concept in two different languages. While *lower case* and *upper case* strongly point in one and only direction in English, the German *Groß- und Kleinbuchstaben* generating your phrases are still somewhat colloquial, the undisputable terms being *Gemeine und Versalien* or even *Minuskeln und Majuskeln*. The latter pair would suggest to coin a phrase like *(j)uskel-unterscheidend* but I admit, that it will never be widely used.

I add a screenshot of the full-text database AskSam, which in its version 6.1 had this toggle button.
[image]

Comment: Cooles Symbol, ja, aber ist mir noch nie begegnet :/ Notepad++: "Groß-/Kleinschreibung", notepad: "Groß-/Kleinschreibung beachten", (Eclipse nutzt es auch nicht, aber da hab ich nur Englische l12n da.)

Comment: In welchen Textverarbeitungsprogrammen gibt es das denn? Ich habe das auch noch nie gesehen.

Comment: @dirkt: siehe Erweiterung meiner Antwort

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Crissov that it would not be too late to introduce a neologism. After all, *case-sensitive* and *case-insensitive* are handy terms, but they are *not* readily understood when encountered for the first time. So, if a German neologism *is* readily understood, and is just as handy, why not? Here is my try:

**groß-klein-abhängig** and **groß-klein-unabhängig**

That’s just one syllable more than the English equivalent (a good ratio). One syllable longer and with no compact negative form is the following:

**groß-klein-unterscheidend** and **nicht groß-klein-unterscheidend**

This last one is not so far from what I consider the best of the three alternatives you found on dict.cc: **Groß- / Kleinschreibung-unterscheidend** (I'm not sure the [spaces around the slash](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%A4gstrich#Typografie) are correct, though).