# German words for “capitalise” vs. “uppercase”

Tags: terminology, capitalization, typography

What would be the German words for *uppercase* (or *all-caps;* all letters uppercase) vs. *capitalise* (first letter uppercase)?

I know of *Großschrift* and have a feeling it fits best for *uppercase* – but what about *capitalise?*  Potentially *groß geschrieben?*

It may well be they're synonymous, but I am unsure.

(The context is, in fact, typography, namely a WYSIWYG editor’s font-style dialog.)

Comment: related: [German translation of “case sensitive”](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/27990/german-translation-of-case-sensitive/)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you refer to a word starting in upper case, like in

> Substantive werden im Deutschen großgeschrieben

"großschreiben" or "groß schreiben" normally refers to the initial letter of a word only.

All uppercase is less commonly used and thus expressed by a printers' technical term as

> SUBSTANTIVE kann man auch in 
>   [image] schreiben

Here *Kapitälchen* refers to a typesetting term that denotes writing a normal size capital followed by slightly undersized uppercase letters - It is also commonly used for "all CAPS", which is thus slightly off meaning.

Another technical term would be

> Dieses Wort ist in VERSALIEN geschrieben

Printers and typesetters also use the term *Versalsatz* for all-uppercase.

(Edit: Had to change the small caps edit of SUBSTANTIVE to a picture - There was nothing wrong with it, but apparently that doesn't render properly on the mobile app)

Edit II: After you have narrowed down your question to labels in a typesetting dialog, I would recommend you use

> Großschreibung

for capitalising words (although I guess typical German writers wouldn't find that function very useful) and

> VERSALIEN

for all-uppercase.

Comment: +1 for *Kapitälchen* and *Versalien*

Comment: How does this answer the question: The difference of uppercase and capitalize?

Comment: @Thomas Not at all, because that wasn't the question.

Comment: @Thomas It does by saying that *capitalising* is *großschreiben* or *groß schreiben* while *uppercase* is *Versalien*. Where is your problem?

Comment: The *Kapitälchen* example is rather misleading, given that what is shown is only the "off meaning" interpretation (which, by the way, I have never encountered - are you sure you are not mixing this up with *small caps*, the English term for *Kapitälchen*? After all, the diminutive in *Kapitälchen* is there for the very reason of expressing that it's *small* capital letters.)

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Please read my "Edit" comment in the answer. The answer used to have that in "Kapitälchen" - Apparently that doesn't render properly in the mobile App and I had to remove it.

Comment: @tofro: Oh, true. In that case, it would probably be preferrable to remove that particular example altogether, or to insert an image showing the effect.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I performed some additional research using the terms you proposed and think that the final two pretty much hit the mark for my scenario. Ta!

Answer (score 5):

There are different terms for *Uppercase* (or: [*All caps*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_caps)) writing: Wikipedia has “[Majuskelschrift, Versalschrift oder Kapitalschrift](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Majuskelschrift)”. I’m not sure if *Großschrift* is synonymous to those terms; personally, I wouldn’t expect all-caps text but text with bigger font size. Anyway, here’s a Google NGram chart of those four terms (I’m quite surprised at the result — I didn’t expect the *Kapitalschrift* would outweight *Versalschrift*):

[image: nGram of the different terms]

Another option would be to use a substantival phrase like *Schreibung in Großbuchstaben*. The plural form *Großbuchstaben* indicates that it isn’t just capitalization (with a single uppercase letter).

### EDIT:

For a WYSIWYG editor font-style dialog, using "GROßBUCHSTABEN" for "*uppercase*" would be an option. This isn't as precise as *Versalien*, *Versalschrift*, or *Majuskelschrift*, but i expect that most users will understand which feature is toggled by that dialog entry. But it may look a little bit "aggressive", since all-caps may be understood as sign for shouting. I would expect "*Großbuchstaben*" to work, too.

For *capitalize*, things are even more difficult, since there's no single word that fits exactly **and** is commonly used by the average user. You *may* use something like "*Erster Buchstabe Groß*" or "*Ersten Buchstaben Großschreiben*. Orthographically, this is wrong, since "groß" is written lower-case when in the middle of a sentence. But this hopefully makes people understand the effect of capitalization. If you want to stick to rules of orthography, you may use the correct version "*erster Buchstabe groß*" or "*ersten Buchstaben großschreiben*".

Comment: Agree that *Großschrift* is ambiguous (font size vs. upper/lower case), also "Kapitalschrift" (By Karl Marx?) made me wonder.

Comment: @tofro Although I am not a German professional :-), but I know another language with the same feature. By analogy, I think in the German case there is a difference between "Großschrift" und "groß Schrift". The second means big fonts, the first the alternative character set. The same distinction goes for "Kapitalschrift" and "kapital Schrift". Although it is visible only in written communication. In the daily verbal practice "Großschrift" is nearly always used in the first sense, and "kapital Schrift" is nearly nonsense.

Comment: @tofro If I had to say "groß Schrift" on German, I would say "größere Buchstaben" oder "höhere Fonts".

Answer (score 2):

Capitalization is frequently used for emphasis, but English and German differ in which words are accepted to be marked this way, because it’s a stronger register in German orthography, where it is applied to the heads of nominal groups (in addition to proper nouns and sentence-initial words as in English). It’s hardly used for purely stylistic purposes in German therefore, whereas it’s quite common in English headlines and titles.

In English as in German, all-uppercase strings of letters are either acronyms – abbreviation dots were more common for those in earlier times in both languages – or stylistically marked. It can become ambiguous if these uses are mixed, i.e. when an acronym occurs in a phrase set in uppercase, hence it’s still customary to write `U.S.` (but `UK`, `UN` and `USA`) in English so it cannot be confused with *us*.

There are other reasons for sure, but this may provide a hint why terminology, both vulgar and technical (by typesetters and typographers), differ between German and English, i.e. why there is no clear distinction between capitalization and uppercasing in German.

Personally, I would use and understand the terms as shown in the following list, but I cannot claim that it was based upon actual research. Please note the use of prepositions *in* and *mit* which can be decisive.

- `arm`

  - *klein[geschrieben]*
  - *in/mit Kleinbuchstaben*
  - *in ?Kleinschrift*
- `Arm`

  - *[am Anfang] groß[geschrieben]*
  - ***mit** [einem] Großbuchstabe[n] [am Anfang]*
  - *mit Majuskel*
  - *Initialmajuskel*
- `ARM`

  - *durchgängig groß[geschrieben]*
  - *in ?Großschrift*
  - *[ganz/durchgängig/vollständig] **in** Großbuchstaben*
  - *nur mit Großbuchstaben*
  - *versal; Versalsatz*
  - *in Versalien [gesetzt]*
  - *in/mit Majuskel**n** [gesetzt]*
  - *in/mit Blockschrift/Blockbuchstaben*
    (but also used to distinguish from connected cursive script)
- `ᴀʀᴍ`

  - ***in** Kapitälchen [gesetzt]*
- `Aʀᴍ`

  - ***mit** Kapitälchen [gesetzt]*

Answer (score 0):

**Capitalize** (first letter uppercase):

> groß schreiben / Großschreibung

**All-Caps**

> Versalien / Majuskeln / Blockschrift / Großbuchstaben

... but "Blockschrift" is mainly used for handwriting

"Großschrift" is generally used to mean large letters, like in books that are intended for elderly readers with bad eyesight. These would normally have upper- and lowercase letters like normal text.

Since the German words for this are not 100% clearly defined, you may want to add example text or write the commands to reflect their effect, as in VERSALIEN.

Comment: [Blockschrift muss nicht ausschließlich aus Großbuchstaben bestehen](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blockschrift).

Comment: IMHO you should avoid _Blockschrift_ in that context, since users may mistake that for _Blocksatz_ (justified alignment).