# Korrekte Schreibung von »Groß-/Kleinschreibung«

Tags: spelling

Die beiden Wörter »*Großschreibung*« und »*Kleinschreibung*« sind Begriffe, die grade dort häufig verwendet werden, wo man zurecht ganz exakt richtige Rechtschreibung und Grammatik erwartet und verlangt: In Unterrichtshilfen für Deutsch. Daher nehme ich an, dass sich gerade Deutsch-Profis bereits den Kopf über folgende Frage zerbrochen haben:

Wenn man über die Schreibung von Wörtern schreibt, möchte man manchmal etwas wie im folgenden Beispiel schreiben:

> Beim Gebrauch eines Verbs als Substantiv, oder auch beim Gebrauch eines Substantivs als Verb, kommt zu einem Wechsel der **Groß-/Kleinschreibung**.

Ich frage mich nun, ob »Groß-/Kleinschreibung« richtig ist, oder ob eine andere Schreibweise besser wäre.

Sehr häufig wird das Problem vermieden, indem man »*Groß- und Kleinschreibung*« schreibt. Ich möchte aber wissen, wie man jenes Wort richtig schreibt, das man in gesprochener Form als [ˈɡʀoːsˌklaɪ̯nˌʃʀaɪ̯bʊŋ] hört.

In Frage kommen zumindest diese Varianten:

- Groß-/Kleinschreibung
- Groß- / Kleinschreibung
- Groß - / Kleinschreibung
- Groß/Kleinschreibung
- Groß- Kleinschreibung
- Groß-Kleinschreibung
- Groß-Klein-Schreibung
- Großkleinschreibung

Weitere Varianten sind denkbar, halte ich aber nicht für Kandidaten für korrekte Schreibungen (lasse mich aber gerne eines Besseren belehren).

Mir fällt auch kein vergleichbarer Begriff ein, von dem ich die Schreibweise ableiten könnte, denn die Wörter die mir einfallen, nämlich *Rot-Grün-Schwäche* und *Hell-Dunkel-Grenze* sind keine Kurzformen von »Rotschwäche und Grünschwäche« oder »Hellgrenze und Dunkelgrenze«

Comment: Der Duden-Verlag, soweit ersichtlich, verwendet ebenfalls _Groß- und Kleinschreibung_. Was spricht dagegen? Wenn Du das aber partout nicht willst, spricht wohl auch nichts gegen _Groß-/Kleinschreibung_, auch hier zwei Wörter, die halt nicht mit und verbunden sind.

Comment: Groß-/Kleinschreibung würde ich auch favorisieren, allerdings ohne fundierten Hintergrund. Bei Google kann man die Begriffe mit Anführungsstrichen eingerahmt suchen, um eine ungefähre Häufung der verschiedenen Schreibweisen zu suchen.

Comment: @Ingmar: Gegen »*Groß- und Kleinschreibung*« spricht gar nichts, das ist total in Ordnung. Aber ich frage hier ausdrücklich NICHT nach der Langform, denn die Kurzform wird ja tatsächlich verwendet, aber es scheint unklar zu sein, wie man das richtig schreibt. Hier in German.SE findet man viele verschiedenen Schreibweisen dafür.

Comment: @Thomas: Häufigkeiten helfen wenig, wenn falsche Varianten ungefähr gleich häufig wie die richtigen sind. Mir geht es nicht darum, wie man das Wort in einem Facebook-Kommentar schieben würde. Ich suche nach einer Lösung, die ein Autor eines Deutsch-Lehrbuchs verwenden könnte.

Comment: Darf ich den -1-Voter um eine kurze Begründung bitten?

Comment: Ich bin mir ziemlich sicher, dass Deine erste Alternative "Groß-/Kleinschreibung" richtig ist. Wenn die zweite Silbe mit Hilfe des "-" weggelassen wird, wird der Bindestrich direkt an die erste Silbe gehängt. Bei den Satzzeichen habe ich die Regel gelernt, dass sie ein führendes Leerzeichen bekommen, wenn sie ein eigenes Wort bedeuten (z. B. "%" = Prozent), andernfalls direkt **ohne** Leerzeichen angehängt werden.

Comment: Thematisch verwandte [Frage](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/27990/1696), die nach einem anderen griffigen Wort für *case sensitive* sucht.

Comment: Ich kann den letzten Absatz der Frage nicht nachvollziehen. Meiner Meinung nach ist der gesuchte Begriff gerade das Unterscheidungsproblem, ob etwas groß oder klein zu schreiben ist und somit genau parallel zur Rot-Grünschwäche oder Hell-Dunkel-Grenze. Sowohl Großschreibung nach Wikipedia als auch Kleinschreibung bedeutet etwas anderes. *letztere sähe zum beispiel so aus*.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Mir war schon klar, daß du etwas fundierteres suchtest. Aber als erste Näherung und mangels anderer Quellen finde ich die Häufigkeitssuche ganz hilfreich.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Der Rechtschreibrat gibt dazu klare Ratschläge:

> § 98
>
> Mit dem Ergänzungsstrich zeigt man an, dass in Zusammensetzungen oder Ableitungen einer Aufzählung ein gleicher Bestandteil ausgelassen wurde, der sinngemäß zu ergänzen ist.

und

> § 106
>
> Mit dem Schrägstrich kennzeichnet man, dass Wörter (Namen, Abkürzungen), Zahlen oder dergleichen zusammengehören.

Aus den jeweiligen Beispielen ist ersichtlich, dass sowohl beim Ergänzungsstrich als auch beim Schrägstrich außer an Wortgrenzen keine Leerzeichen zu setzen sind. Deswegen fällt schon eine große Anzahl deiner Beispiele weg.

Damit ist (für mich), auch anhand der dort jeweils gegebenen Beispiele, eindeutig ersichtlich, dass die einzig richtige Variante

> Groß-/Kleinschreibung

sein muss.

Es *gäbe* theoretisch die Möglichkeit, den Begriff nicht als Auslassung zu betrachten, sondern nur als Zusammensetzung (analog zum vorhandenen Beispiel "Links-rechts-Kombination", man betrachtet den Gesamtbegriff damit nicht als eine Zusammensetzung aus "Großschreibung" und "Kleinschreibung", sondern als Zusammensetzung aus "groß", "klein" und "Schreibung"). Dann wäre

> Groß-klein-Schreibung

auch als richtig zu betrachten (Man beachte hier die Groß-/Kleinschreibung! In deinem vorletzten Beispiel damit leider falsch, leider in den Regeln nicht erklärt, warum...). Diese Verwendung wäre zumindestens nach den Beispielen nicht falsch, aber meiner Erfahrung nach auch nicht gebräuchlich.

Comment: Warum ein Leerzeichen vor dem Schrägstrich fehlen soll, würde ich nicht alleine aus den Beispielen herleiten wollen, aber mangels einer anderen Regelung ist das wohl der allgemeine Konsens.

Comment: Leider scheint es das Regelwerk nur als PDF zu geben oder kennt ihr bessere Quellen, ich meine als HTML mit den Paragraphen?

Comment: @Thomas Das offizielle Regelwerk ist meines Wissens nur als PDF zugänglich. Die amtlichen Regeln enthalten aber auch nur sehr wenige Vorgaben zur Typographie – die nicht zu setzenden Leerzeichen um einen Schrägstrich sind allerdings typographisch und weniger rechschreiberisch bedingt.

Answer (score 3):

> Ich möchte aber wissen, wie man jenes Wort richtig schreibt, das man in gesprochener Form als [ˈɡʀoːsˌklaɪ̯nˌʃʀaɪ̯bʊŋ] hört.

Ich kenne kein entsprechendes Wort wie von dir in diesem Satz beschrieben. Rein semantisch ist ein solches Wort auch wenig sinnvoll, denn wenn es ein Wort wäre, müsste *groß* wie *klein* gleichberechtig dazugehören. Das erkennt man an deinen Beispielen wie *Hell-dunkel-Grenze:* Es handelt sich dabei um eine Grenze *zwischen hell und dunkel,* die also sowohl *hell* als auch *dunkel* gleichermaßen umfasst. Wenn man von Groß-/Kleinschreibung spricht, meint man aber explizit *oder* – es gibt keinen Buchstaben, der sowohl groß als auch klein geschrieben wird.

Sobald man sich von der Prämisse, es handele sich um ein einziges Wort, (die ich, wie erwähnt, aus meinem Alltag so nicht bestätigen kann) ist es relativ offensichtlich, dass die korrekte Schreibung aus den Gründen, die tofro nennt, nur folgende sein kann:

> Groß-/Kleinschreibung

---

Zwei kleine typographische Anmerkungen zu einigen deiner Vorschläge:

- Ein Schrägstrich `/`, sofern er die Bedeutung »A oder B« oder »A und B« in sich trägt, wird stets kompress, also ohne umgebende Leerzeichen gesetzt. Davon zu unterscheiden ist ein Schrägstrich, der bei der Wiedergabe von Lyrik Zeilenumbrüche darstellen soll, die im Text aus welchem Grund auch immer nicht gesetzt werden; dieser Schrägstrich wird mit umgebenden Leerzeichen gesetzt.

  > Großer Plattfisch dort im Meer / Komm und schwimme zu mir her / Meine Frau, die Ilsebill, / Will nicht so, wie ich es will.

  Da es sich nicht um die Wiedergabe von Lyrik handelt, fallen Varianten wie <del>»Groß- / Kleinschreibung«</del> aus.
- Ein horizontaler Strich kann nur dann ein Binde- oder Auslassungsstrich sein, wenn er direkt mit dem zugehörigen Wort verbunden ist. Ein horizontaler Strich, der links und rechts von Leerzeichen umgeben ist, ist in der deutschsprachigen Typographie stets ein Gedankenstrich, der Satzteile und nicht Wortteile trennt. Korrekterweise wird ein Gedankenstrich als Halbgeviertstrich »–« gesetzt, häufig aber mangels Erreichbarkeit des korrekten Striches als Divis (obwohl das einen zu kleinen Zwischenraum zur Folge hat). Dies schließt die Variante aus, in welcher der Bindestrich vollständig von Leerzeichen umgeben ist.

Comment: *Mandje! Mandje! Timpe Te! /  Buttje! Buttje in de See! / Mine Fru, de Ilsebill, / Will nich so, as ick wol will.* - wenn schon, dann das Original ;)

Comment: @Takkat Schiebs auf meinen seligen Deutschlehrer, der uns in der fünften Klasse eine hochdeutsche Version hat lesen lassen ;)