# How to translate "case folding" (IT, computers)

Tags: translation

EN: I'm looking for the proper german translation of the term "[case folding](https://www.w3.org/International/wiki/Case_folding)". The linked page explains what it is.

DE: Ich suche eine passende Übersetzung bzw. die dt. Variante des Fachbegriffs "[case folding](https://www.w3.org/International/wiki/Case_folding)". (Nähere Erklärung auf der verlinkten Seite.)

Comment: Note that german translations of IT technical terms often tend to sound clumsy, and often cause more confusion, rather than clarifying anything.

Comment: Welcome to German.SE. Please include a short quote from the linked website what "case folding" is defined at. That gives the question an understanding without clicking anywhere else to grasp the core idea.

Comment: Tatsächlich halte ich das ganze *folding* für überholt: Such- oder Sortieralgorithmen können heute praktisch alle schreibungsunabhängig operieren, siehe [diese Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/27990/1696), damit fällt der Anlass für den Vorgang weitgehend weg. Mit zunehmendem Umfang (was *Big Data* nahelegt) wird es ohnehin immer weniger praktikabel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Ich suche eine passende Übersetzung bzw. die dt. Variante

Deutsche IT-ler tendieren dazu die englischen Begriffe einfach zu übernehmen anstatt sich neue auszudenken. Das gilt vor allem für "neuere" Begriffe. Dementsprechend ist der gebräuchlichste Begriff ganz einfach

> Casefolding / Case-Folding

der auch gern falsch als

> Case Folding

geschrieben wird.

Das besondere an dieser Aneignung ist, dass das Wort dann auch grammatikalisch eingedeutscht und entsprechend verwendet werden kann.

Schön kann man das etwa am verwandten Begriff des Mapping sehen. Der wird etwa gerne mal gemappt.

Comment: Vielen Dank! Bin auch deutscher IT'ler - und störe mich an dieser Angewohnheit. Hätte gerne ein deutsches Wort verwendet - doch das scheint es nicht zu geben. Sofern nicht noch eine bessere Antwort kommt, bleibe ich dann bei Case-Folding...

Comment: @MBaas auch ich verwende gerne deutsche Begriffe (Eingabetaste, Umstelltaste, Steuerelement, Optionsfeld, instanziieren...), aber wie schon andere schrieben: manchmal gibt es nicht mal annähernd ein deutsches Wort dafür - bestes Beispiel: "Performance" wurde nie als "Leistung" anerkannt, stattdessen wird "Performanz" im Duden geführt.

Comment: @AmigoJack Jepp, schönes Beispiel!

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing more precise than just [Normalisierung](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalisierung_(Text)). Since in German upper and lower case letters have their own meanings traditionally there never emerged the need to have an intermediate form. In Programming a common concept is to "alles in Kleinbuchstaben umwandeln." If you need a German translation, adapt to that practice textually.

Comment: Thanks - that sounded great, but reading through that link, I stumbled upon "müssen bei der Normalisierung visuell ähnliche Zeichen durch dasselbe Zeichen ersetzt werden. Es könnte also sowohl die Ziffer 1, als auch der Kleinbuchstabe l durch den Großbuchstaben I ersetzt werden." - which IMHO goes beyond case-folding.

Comment: Yes, it goes beyond, because it aims at Normalisierung in general. The point is: there is no German term for case folding, only the phrase "in Kleinbuchstaben" which isn't even exactly fitting case folding either.

Comment: @MBaas the sentence you quoted is just an example - Normalisierung definitely applies to your use case, it's just that Case Folding is a little bit more specific. On the other hand, "Normalisierung" conveys the general meaning to a person that does not know the technical term "Case Folding".

Comment: The linked article describes exactly why the common approach "alles in Kleinbuchstaben umwandeln" is a fallacy and doesn't solve the problem. German is one of the languages where converting from lowercase to uppercase and vice versa are not opposite operations, consider for example something like this: `strcmp(tolower("Fuß"),tolower("FUSS"))` With proper case folding, "Fuß" and "FUSS" should be considered equal if doing a case insensitive comparison.

Comment: @jarnbjo: Given the introduction of upper case "ß", see [wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gro%C3%9Fes_%C3%9F) and official adoption in 2017 your argument is weakened.

Comment: @guidot Not for a very long time. As long as SS is a valid representation of a capitalized ß and as long as you want to or have to support older texts,  "Fuß" and "FUSS" should still be considered equal if doing a case insensitive comparison. Even if the capitalized ẞ now exists and is officially 'acknowledged' I don't think I have ever seen it actually used in practice.

Answer (score 0):

Ich würde das einfach als

*Umwandlung in Kleinbuchstaben*

übersetzen.

Weil das das ist, was es ist.

Comment: Nicht immer - es kommt auf die Implementierung an. Casefolding kann auch die Umwandlung in Großbuchstaben bedeuten. Außerdem ist Casefolding unterschiedlich zum normalen "strolower", "toLowerCase()", etc. In Python werden etwa mit dem casefold()-Befehl die ß in ss umgewandelt. Auch was mit griechischen oder anderen "besonderen" Buchstaben passiert ist immer eine gute Frage. Der Sinn von Casefolding ist vergleichbare Strings zu erhalten, nicht Kleinbuchstaben (auch wenn der Effekt im Englischen so gut wie immer derselbe ist).

Comment: Nicht jede Sprache kennt Groß- und Kleinbuchstaben, ist aber trotzdem von case folding betroffen - selbst "Umwandlung in Kleinbuchstaben" mit lediglich deutschem Vorstellungshorizont vernachlässigt Fälle zwischen `ö` und `oe` und `o¨`.